# Using a column values within the round function

Tags: python, python-polars

I have this dataframe:

```py
shape: (5, 3)
┌───────────────┬──────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ exchange_rate ┆ sig_figs_len ┆ reverse_rate_from_euro │
│ ---           ┆ ---          ┆ ---                    │
│ f64           ┆ u32          ┆ f64                    │
╞═══════════════╪══════════════╪════════════════════════╡
│ 6.4881        ┆ 5            ┆ 0.154128               │
│ 6.5196        ┆ 5            ┆ 0.153384               │
│ 6.4527        ┆ 5            ┆ 0.154974               │
│ 6.41          ┆ 3            ┆ 0.156006               │
│ 6.425         ┆ 4            ┆ 0.155642               │
└───────────────┴──────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

I would like to round the value of in every cell of the `reverse_rate_from_euro` with the matching value in the corresponding cell of the `sig_figs_len` column.

I came up with a solution which uses the apply/map_rows function, but since the dataset is quite big and using apply/pure python isn't an optimized ideal solution to go about it, i would like to find a better solution.

Here's the snippet:

```py
df = df.with_columns(
    (df.map_rows(lambda df_: round(df_[-1], df_[-2])))
    .to_series()
    .alias("reverse_rate_to_euro_rounded_sig_figs")
```

Is there a better solution that uses any of the built-in Polars expressions API?

result set should look like so:

```py
shape: (5, 4)
┌───────────────┬──────────────┬────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ exchange_rate ┆ sig_figs_len ┆ reverse_rate_from_euro ┆ reverse_rate_to_euro_rounded_sig… │
│ ---           ┆ ---          ┆ ---                    ┆ ---                               │
│ f64           ┆ u32          ┆ f64                    ┆ f64                               │
╞═══════════════╪══════════════╪════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ 6.4881        ┆ 5            ┆ 0.154128               ┆ 0.15413                           │
│ 6.5196        ┆ 5            ┆ 0.153384               ┆ 0.15338                           │
│ 6.4527        ┆ 5            ┆ 0.154974               ┆ 0.15497                           │
│ 6.41          ┆ 3            ┆ 0.156006               ┆ 0.156                             │
│ 6.425         ┆ 4            ┆ 0.155642               ┆ 0.1556                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────┴────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

Any input is highly appreciated!
thanks for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably do something like this:

```py
df.with_columns(
    (
        pl.col('reverse_rate_from_euro') * 
        pl.lit(10).pow(pl.col('sig_figs_len'))
    ).round() * 
    pl.lit(0.1).pow(pl.col('sig_figs_len'))
)

┌───────────────┬──────────────┬────────────────────────┐
│ exchange_rate ┆ sig_figs_len ┆ reverse_rate_from_euro │
│ ---           ┆ ---          ┆ ---                    │
│ f64           ┆ i64          ┆ f64                    │
╞═══════════════╪══════════════╪════════════════════════╡
│ 6.4881        ┆ 3            ┆ 0.154                  │
│ 6.5196        ┆ 4            ┆ 0.1534                 │
└───────────────┴──────────────┴────────────────────────┘
```

alternatively, if you know that number of different `sig_figs_len` values is not large, you can just enumerate over [`unique()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.unique.html#polars.Series.unique) values and create result with [`coalesce()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.coalesce.html) and [`when()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.when.html):

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.coalesce(
        pl.when(pl.col("sig_figs_len") == x)
        .then(pl.col("reverse_rate_from_euro").round(x))
        for x in df['sig_figs_len'].unique()
    ).alias('reverse_rate_to_euro_rounded_sig_figs')
)

┌───────────────┬──────────────┬────────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────┐
│ exchange_rate ┆ sig_figs_len ┆ reverse_rate_from_euro ┆ reverse_rate_to_euro_rounded_sig… │
│ ---           ┆ ---          ┆ ---                    ┆ ---                               │
│ f64           ┆ i64          ┆ f64                    ┆ f64                               │
╞═══════════════╪══════════════╪════════════════════════╪═══════════════════════════════════╡
│ 6.4881        ┆ 3            ┆ 0.154128               ┆ 0.154                             │
│ 6.5196        ┆ 4            ┆ 0.153384               ┆ 0.1534                            │
└───────────────┴──────────────┴────────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────┘
```

Essentially, what we do here is creating a `Iterable[IntoExpr]` which you can see as a list of columns where each column contains only values rounded to certain `sig_figs_len` value:

```py
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col("sig_figs_len") == x)
    .then(pl.col("reverse_rate_from_euro").round(x)).name.suffix(f"_{x}")
     for x in df['sig_figs_len'].unique()
))

┌───────────────┬──────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┐
│ exchange_rate ┆ sig_figs_len ┆ reverse_rate_from_e ┆ reverse_rate_from_e ┆ reverse_rate_from_e ┆ reverse_rate_from_e │
│ ---           ┆ ---          ┆ uro                 ┆ uro_3               ┆ uro_4               ┆ uro_5               │
│ f64           ┆ i64          ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 │
│               ┆              ┆ f64                 ┆ f64                 ┆ f64                 ┆ f64                 │
╞═══════════════╪══════════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╡
│ 6.4881        ┆ 5            ┆ 0.154128            ┆ null                ┆ null                ┆ 0.15413             │
│ 6.5196        ┆ 5            ┆ 0.153384            ┆ null                ┆ null                ┆ 0.15338             │
│ 6.4527        ┆ 5            ┆ 0.154974            ┆ null                ┆ null                ┆ 0.15497             │
│ 6.41          ┆ 3            ┆ 0.156006            ┆ 0.156               ┆ null                ┆ null                │
│ 6.425         ┆ 4            ┆ 0.155642            ┆ null                ┆ 0.1556              ┆ null                │
└───────────────┴──────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

and then we use the fact that `pl.coalesce()` accept iterable of `Expr` to get first non-null column

Comment: Using `pl.coalesce` is probably the ideomatic way to handle this. Nice!

Comment: yep unless amount of unique `sig_figs_len` values is large, then it might be less performant. just guessing here though

Comment: thanks @RomanPekar!
both solutions are good! should have thought about the 1st myself.

i have one question, i tried to use the second apporach, using `pl.when`, but without `pl.coalesce` however i get an error. it works perfectly when using `pl.coalesce` though. what does pl.coalesce actually do under the hood? i always thought `pl.coalesce` is the same as `if_null`. but it seems that there's more to it then meets the eye